# Null / Out of Bounds Error when running Liquibase

Tags: grails, liquibase

I am using the database-migration Grails plugin. But running dbm-update runs into fatal errors for some of my sql when using the liquibase formatted sql migrations. I get this error:

```
liquibase : 'Change Set GraphFunctions.sql::graph_functions_initialize_1::<user> failed.  Error: null'
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

This happens when I run the code:

```
--changeset <username>:graph_functions_initialize_1
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_trcd(
    IN new_parent_id bigint,
    IN new_child_id bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(ancestor_id bigint, descendant_id bigint, paths bigint, cost bigint) AS '
    SELECT
        t1.ancestor_id AS ancestor_id,
        t2.descendant_id AS descendant_id,
        SUM(t1.paths*t2.paths)::bigint AS paths,
        MIN(t1."cost"+t2."cost")+1::bigint AS "cost"
    FROM db_set_membership_closure t1, db_set_membership_closure t2
    WHERE t1.descendant_id=new_parent_id AND t2.ancestor_id=NEW_child_id
    GROUP BY t1.ancestor_id, t2.descendant_id
    UNION
    SELECT
        NEW_parent_id AS ancestor_id,
        descendant_id AS descendant_id,
        paths AS paths ,
        (c."cost" + 1)::bigint AS "cost"
    FROM db_set_membership_closure c
    WHERE ancestor_id = NEW_child_id
    UNION
    SELECT
        ancestor_id AS ancestor_id,
        NEW_child_id AS descendant_id,
        paths AS paths,
        c."cost" + 1::bigint AS "cost"
    FROM db_set_membership_closure c
    WHERE descendant_id = NEW_parent_id
    UNION VALUES (NEW_parent_id, NEW_child_id,1::bigint,1::bigint);
' LANGUAGE sql;
--rollback drop function build_trcd;
```

If I don't use formatted-sql then it runs fine. However, if I do that, then I cannot manage a rollback through the Liquibase interface. Does anyone have an insight into what I might change to make this work?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with liquibase formatted sql not being able to run postgres create function statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that sql changesets including function declarations have been failing because they contain semi-colons in the middle of the create statement. To fix these errors I just had to change the formatted-sql to not split the statements:

```
--changeset <username>:graph_functions_initialize_1 splitStatements:false
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was having issues with Dropwizard and a Postgres (plpgsql) script.